# Flutter chat bubble text not aligned

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter to build a Chat Application.

In my message bubbles, I display the message text, the date, and an icon to show if the message was read or not. The text of the message is poorly displayed. It goes to the next line after just one or two words instead of filling the full width of the bubble.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
  horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 80.0, right: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: primaryColor.withOpacity(.1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                documentSnapshot.data['text'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                documentSnapshot.data["time"] != null
                  ? DateFormat.MMMd().add_jm()
                    .format(documentSnapshot.data["time"].toDate())
                    .toString()
                  : "",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: secondryColor,
                  fontSize: 13.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              documentSnapshot.data['isRead'] == false
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.done,
                    color: secondryColor,
                    size: 15,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.done_all,
                    color: primaryColor,
                    size: 15,
                  )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Currently, you are using a `Row` Widget to display the message text as the first child and then the date and read icon as the second child:

[image]

Instead, you should use a `Column` Widget.

[image]

## Full solution

After going back and forth with Julien

[image]

### 1. Domain Layer

```
class ChatEntry {
  final String text;
  final DateTime date;
  final bool read;
  final bool sent;

  ChatEntry({
    this.text,
    this.date,
    this.read,
    this.sent,
  });
}
```

### 2. Chat Bubble

```
class Bubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final ChatEntry entry;

  const Bubble({Key key, this.entry}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: entry.sent ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        padding: kBubblePadding,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: (entry.sent ? kSentColor : kReceivedColor)
              .withOpacity(entry.read ? kReadOpacity : 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(kBorderRadius),
            topRight: Radius.circular(kBorderRadius),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(entry.sent ? 0.0 : kBorderRadius),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(entry.sent ? kBorderRadius : 0.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment:
              entry.sent ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(entry.text, style: kBubbleTextStyle),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  DateFormat('MMMd – kk:mm').format(entry.date),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: kBubbleMetaFontSize),
                ),
                if (entry.read) ...[
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Icon(Icons.done, size: kBubbleMetaFontSize)
                ]
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### 3. Chat Conversation

```
class Conversation extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ChatEntry> entries;

  const Conversation({Key key, this.entries}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: entries
          .map(
            (entry) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Bubble(entry: entry),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

### 4. Application

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Chat Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Conversation(entries: getChatEntries()),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

## Full Source Code for easy copy-paste

Together with random data generation.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Chat Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Conversation(entries: getChatEntries()),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Conversation extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ChatEntry> entries;

  const Conversation({Key key, this.entries}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: entries
          .map(
            (entry) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Bubble(entry: entry),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Bubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final ChatEntry entry;

  const Bubble({Key key, this.entry}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: entry.sent ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        padding: kBubblePadding,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: (entry.sent ? kSentColor : kReceivedColor)
              .withOpacity(entry.read ? kReadOpacity : 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(kBorderRadius),
            topRight: Radius.circular(kBorderRadius),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(entry.sent ? 0.0 : kBorderRadius),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(entry.sent ? kBorderRadius : 0.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment:
              entry.sent ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(entry.text, style: kBubbleTextStyle),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  DateFormat('MMMd – kk:mm').format(entry.date),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: kBubbleMetaFontSize),
                ),
                if (entry.read) ...[
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Icon(Icons.done, size: kBubbleMetaFontSize)
                ]
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// DOMAIN

class ChatEntry {
  final String text;
  final DateTime date;
  final bool read;
  final bool sent;

  ChatEntry({
    this.text,
    this.date,
    this.read,
    this.sent,
  });
}

// CONFIG

const kSentColor = Color(0xff03bd85);
const kReceivedColor = Color(0xff0251d6);
const kReadOpacity = .3;
const kBorderRadius = 15.0;
const kBubblePadding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
  horizontal: 15.0,
  vertical: 10.0,
);
const kBubbleTextStyle = const TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black87,
  fontSize: 16.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
);
const kBubbleMetaFontSize = 11.0;

// RANDOM DATA

final Random random = Random.secure();
final faker = new Faker();

List<ChatEntry> getChatEntries() {
  final nbMessages = random.nextInt(17) + 3;
  final lastRead = random.nextInt(nbMessages);
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  return List.generate(
    nbMessages,
    (index) {
      date = date.subtract(Duration(minutes: random.nextInt(30)));
      return ChatEntry(
        text: faker.lorem
            .words(2 + random.nextInt(random.nextBool() ? 3 : 15))
            .join(' '),
        date: date,
        read: index >= lastRead,
        sent: random.nextBool(),
      );
    },
  ).reversed.toList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the solution worked well but if i put small text it will align it to the right, long text worked fin

Comment: This is due to the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` of the `Column`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome Thierry, its working perfectly as intended, if want shape the bubble would be easy to add that little shape?

Comment: I think that's where I start asking for due salary. Hahaha! 

Comment: Check here, maybe: https://prabhanu.medium.com/whatsapps-chat-bubble-for-your-flutter-app-b1793bf81c87

Comment: Maybe i will need you, for that little project of course tu seras rémunéré

Comment: Is it possible to make the text going until the tick sign  its still little bit shorter I think its iinside a container? ColoredBox( so it can't go further

Comment: The chat bubbles width is currently defined as `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65`. I will update the answer for a variable width depending on the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot was very helpful, i left time and date stamp outside the bubble so it can resize according the to text